# Why am I unable to spyOn this "global" function?

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

First time trying to use Jasmine spies so I hope I'm just missing something obvious. What I want to do is track calls to a function that I have defined as:

```
window.myFunction = ->
```

I have a class method that calls this function. The method works fine, and I can test most aspects of it, but the following fails:

```
beforeEach ->
  spyOn(window, 'myFunction').andCallThrough()

it 'should do that thing', ->
  MyClass.makesCallToMyFunction
  expect(window.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

What am I doing wrong? I've seen plenty of examples on SO and many of them use the spyOn(window, 'myFunction')...expect(window.myFunction) setup/spec.

Any insight is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fail:

```
it 'should do that thing', ->
  MyClass.makesCallToMyFunction
  expect(window.myFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

because `MyClass.makesCallToMyFunction` is not a method call, that's simply a reference to the `makesCallToMyFunction` function. If you want to call a CoffeeScript function/method without any arguments then you need to include the parentheses or CoffeeScript won't know that you want to call the function:

```
MyClass.makesCallToMyFunction()
```

Comment: That was it! Tired oversight on my part. Thanks!